# Fortigate logging: how to prevent ping to firewall interface to be logged while still getting logs for implicitly denied traffic

Tags: firewall, fortigate, logging, fortinet

Is there a way to configure a fortinet firewall (e.g, fortigate600 running FortiOS 5 or FortiOS 4) so it do not generate log entries for pings that are directed to the firewall's own interfaces but still do generate log entries for implicitly denied traffic?

In both cases, the log entries specifies the policy with id '0' as the policy generating the log message.

In the case of successful pings, 'status' is set to 'accept' in the log and the VDOM name is set as the 'dstintf'.

I have tried to create firewall rules that match the ping traffic directed to local firewall interfaces, with the intent to explicitly disable logging, but I failed to come up with a rule that manage to match the traffic.  Also, there is the option to disable the logging for implicit rule 0 (the implicit 'deny' rule at the bottom of the policy) but that also disables the logging of denied traffic, which is not what I want.

Pinging firewall interfaces (for determining that the firewall interface is available) is relied upon in certain situations and can not always be designed away. (E.g is some setups using load balancers).  Also, being able to configure network equipment to avoid unwanted logging messages from being generated is always desirable, to keep down the amount of "noise" that is sent to external logging servers (Splunk etc), and in our case, logs about those 'heartbeat pings' is just considered noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Fortigate firewalls running FortiOS 5.0 or newer, it is possible to use the CLI to specifically disable logs for accepted traffic directed to the firewall itself:

Log on to firewall using SSH, then run the following commands (assuming the firewall has a VDOM named 'root')

```
config vdom
edit root
config log settings
set local-in-allow disable
```

This has to be done on a per VDOM basis.

Once this is done, the firewall keeps logging all denied traffic, without logging accepted pings, SNMP monitoring queries etc.

Fortinet has more informationg here: http://docs-legacy.fortinet.com/fgt/handbook/cli_html/index.html#page/FortiOS%25205.0%2520CLI/config_log.17.13.html

For Fortigate firewalls running FortiOS older than 5.0, I suppose the best advice is to upgrade to 5.0 or newer and then apply the setting suggested above.  It seems like the feature 'set local-in-allow disable' is not available before FortiOS 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

A policy allowing ping only from specific addresses following by a policy that denies ping from any source. havent tested it, but if it falls on a policy, it shouldnt get to the implicit rule.

Another option is to restrict admin login from specific host. you can restrict the admin login to all addresses that you need ping from and addresses that needs access to the fortigate. if anyone else tries to ping, it will be blocked before it gets to the policies.

Comment: Assume a net 192.168.1.0/24 with a pinging host 192.168.1.10 and a firewall interface called FOOINT with IP 192.168.1.1.

In that case, how would you suggest the destination interface + IP should be specified in a rule that will match ICMP pings from the pinging host to the IP address of FOOINT?

I have tested all kinds of ways to specify the source interface + address and destination interface + address.  No matter what they look like, as soon as the FW interface IP itself is pinged, the ping results in a log entry referring to implicit rule 0 as if all firewall rules was simply bypassed.

Comment: I think i did rush with my reply :)

Comment: I was able to recreate this with 5.2.1, the denied pings are in the local traffic as it is traffic to/from the system (the VDOM). I could only filter them out with the service tab, filtered ping and checked the 'not' box. Ive tried to find something through the CLI but no luck there. I dont think it is possible to not generate these logs at all, but maybe try the chat with fortinet and see if they have an idea.

Comment: Yes, I will ask fortinet if they know how to do this.